# System.Convert.ChangeType for binding commas

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

I have this line of code:

```
System.Convert.ChangeType(input, destinationType, CultureString);
```

If called with a culture of de-DE and input is 4,50 and destinationType is double it returns 4.50.

If I call the same with en-GB it converts it to 450.00.

Is there a way to make it return 4.50 or throw an exception saying you can't convert 4,50 to double.

Thanks

Comment: Pass the Culture which corresponds to the conversion rules you want. That is how the API is designed.

Comment: @driis thanks, can you expand a bit more? destination type may be any primitive type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx) on the specific overload you are using:

> Returns an object of the specified type whose value is equivalent to the specified object. A parameter supplies culture-specific formatting information.

In other words, it tries to understand how to convert based on the culture's formatting information. So `4,50` means `4.5` in **de-DE** yet the same number is identified as `4.50` in **en-GB** (Notice there is a *period* not a comma).
A comma is used in the en-GB culture to talk about thousands (e.g 4000 can be written `4,000`) when 4,50 is parsed, the comma is ignored and therefor the output is 450.

This is just like the date *21st of January 2010* is parsed `01/21/10` (mm/dd/yy) in the US yet it is parsed `21/01/10` (dd/mm/yy) in the UK.

So actually, no exception *should* be raised since  4,50 *CAN* be converted to a double, depends where in the world :)

Note: C# has the [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) when you want culture-independent conversions.

If you want to throw an exception, *don't use ChangeType*, use `Double.Parse` with the `NumberStyles` just like @ChrisF explained in *his* answer.
This for instance will throw an exception:

```
Double.Parse("4,50", NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: I'm from the UK and I wouldn't say that 4,50 represents 450.0 though

Comment: @Jon - it's just that the thousands separators are ignored when parsing the string, so you have any number and in any position.

Comment: @Jon think of 4,50 as 450 since you ignore the comma, just like 4,500 will be 4500 when converted.

Comment: @ChrisF, Blachshma: the point being made I think is not how the implementation works but how it *should* work.`4,50` is not a valid number as written in english. If I was handed that to type in somewhere the most obvious thoughts in my mind are a) that a trailing 0 got missed off or b) that a `,` was used instead of a `.`. I think the original poster is wanting it to throw an exception in this situation and asking if it is possible (and I think its a quite sensible request really).

Comment: @ChrisF - Agree accepted answer should be yours... - Updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

You should use `double.Parse` rather than `ChangeType`.

You can get `double.Parse` to throw an exception if you **don't** set the `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` flag:

> NumberStyles.AllowThousands indicates that group separators are allowed. Valid group separator characters are determined by the NumberGroupSeparator or CurrencyGroupSeparator properties of the current NumberFormatInfo object.

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In this case you could use:

```
double result = double.Parse("4,50", numberStyle);
```

As it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx)

> A typical value to specify is a combination of Float combined with AllowThousands.

So in your case you want to make sure that this flag is not set. Though it would mean that you couldn't correctly parse "4,500".

By setting the flag you tell the code to simply ignore the thousands separator when parsing the string. This means that according to the algorithm the following string all convert to 450:

> 450
>   45,0
>   4,50
>   450,

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.Parse(input, style)`

The parsing is much stricter and the `System.Globalization.NumberStyles style` allows you to specify exactly what you do and don't consider to be a number. It will throw a `FormatException` if it doesn't like what is in the string.